# Whats the best way to show resolvable notifications?

Tags: notification

Example: in a dashboard, mostly i saw it on the header next to messages and user profile/name using a bell icons similar to the image below:

[image]

On the other hand (this is what I am using now), i have all my resolvable notifications  right below the header. Not really sure if it is the best way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (your example) is how most systems I've seen do this, and it works fine - having it big and near the top, for important messages, is a good thing.

The things to note, for me, are

1. Make sure you don't over-do it! Only put important things here, and try to set things up so that there isn't something there often - otherwise your users will just grow accustomed to it and will ignore it.
2. Give them a hint! Right now it's just an error message: why? Give them a "More" or "Resolve" or similar link, so that they can actually follow it to be able to quickly fix the problem
3. Consider an "Ignore" or "Resolve" or "Close" or similar button, where relevant - if it's possible that the error isn't truly an *error*, let the user get rid of it (this ties back into point #1)

Comment: Once a user click a specific notification, it directs to the the screen where it should be resolved, once done, it automatically hides the notification on the dashboard/main page, it will only appear again if the user refreshes the page or login again.

Comment: does hiding it with a bell icon (with number of resolvable notifications) on the header will have the difference in terms of user experience?

Comment: Comment 1: Is that obvious to the user? I wouldn't have guessed so from your screenshot, but it's hard to tell from a static image. If in doubt, make it more obvious. A bell icon is more useful for non-urgent notifications, and that's a call you have to take: a notifications icon is far more likely to be ignored than a banner, however. Important (act now) notifications are better off somewhere they can't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The best way depends on the design.

It seems like you have a **left menu**, **3 central blocks** where content will be displayed and a small **top navigation bar**.

Taking in count that you have a pretty space between top and main content, and you did a good job taking the max. width, contrasting colors and placing the notifications there, it could be the best solution for you.

But hey, you can take a look at Stack Exchange's system, it fits in almost every page and it's very useful.